# How to auto-scroll down when my page loads In Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I write the below code to a footer.php file. This works but is applied for all the pages. I want to apply page scroll in one page only.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
    jQuery('body').animate({scrollTop: +400}, 1000);
    
});
</script>
```

Can any one help me on how to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a contidional statemnent on the footer.php file to only  execute the jquery code if it is in only in the current page you wish for.

something like this example below

```
<?php
global $post;
$target_pageid = 7654;
$current_pageid =  $post->ID;

if (current_pageid == $target_pageid){
?>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('body').animate({scrollTop: +400}, 1000);

});

<?php
}
?>
```